# use jquery on DOM that has been added afterwards with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

here is the case. with jquery ajax call i have added a new link < a id="new_link >

and i want to use jquery on that newly added link:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.post("static/js/jquery_call.php", function(data){
        $("#div_id").html(data);
    });

    $("#new_link").click(function(){

    ..... (and so on)
```

but it doesnt allow me because this link was added after the DOM has been generated. I can manipulate all other links but not the new added one. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `function(data)` handler is invoked when the ajax request *is finished* (all data present). In the meanwhile the execution of the script continues. Meaning that your `$("#new_link")...` code most likely is executed before the data has been added to the dom.
Either use a [live handler](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) or at least move your $("#new_link") code inside the function(data) { } handler.

edit: example code

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $.post("static/js/jquery_call.php", function(data){
    $("#div_id").html(data).find("#new_link").click( function() {
      alert("Test");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this question is asked every other day. boy, have i milked from it

```
$("#new_link").live('click',function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.live()` function ([doc here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)) to bind to existing and newly created elements:

```
$("#new_link").live("click", function(){
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: can i ask you how you could answer this fast? do you subscribe to new threads? or did you just click on this tread but accident?

Comment: Haha, I was in the jQuery-tagged section and I happened to hit refresh and saw the new question and immediately knew the answer. I'm taking a break at work :-D

Comment: ok i c=) is it possible to subscribe to new messages in your favurite tags? i have not an account yet.

Comment: You can use the RSS feed (right corner of your address bar) or jsut look at specific tags, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery -- content comes in so fast that you can wait 10 seconds, hit refresh and there is a lot of new stuff.